# display data from 1 tablet to 2 filtered datagridview in vb net

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagridview, datatable

I have two datagridview controls and one table. I am trying to display data with one filter on dgv1 and multiple filters on dgv2. Basically what i am asking is dgv 1 should display all customers with a cutdate in the month of july, and dgv2 should display all records for customer john in the month of july. both the dgv's are pulling records from the same table.

my problem is that both of these are displaying the same info. 
This is what i have so far.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbprov = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    dbsource = "Data Source = C:\Users\Sonu\Desktop\VB_Projects\database1.accdb"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM T_Cutdata"
    sqlDelete = "SELECT * FROM T_DeletedData"
    con.ConnectionString = dbprov & dbsource
    con.Open()
    'MsgBox("Open")
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "lawncutdata")

    Dim dv_all As DataView = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv_all
    dv_all.RowFilter = "cutdate>='07/01/2014' and cutdate<='07/10/2014'"
    '"CustomerID = '" + s_customerID +"'"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv_all

    Dim dv_one As DataView = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").DefaultView
    dGridOneCustomer.DataSource = dv_one
    dv_one.RowFilter = "cutday='" + currentday + "' and customer_name='" + custname + "'"
    '"CustomerID = '" + s_customerID +"'"
    dGridOneCustomer.DataSource = dv_one
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why its doing that. I am thinking that i may need to create a new dataset and bind the second dgv to that dataset. Please help, I am stuck.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that you are referencing the same objects with `dv_all.RowFilter` and `dv_one.RowFilter`.

Using `Dim dv_one As DataView = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").Copy().DefaultView` for your second `DataGridView` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `DataView` (the default view of the table) in both grids. All you have to do is create two new data views.

```
Dim dv_all As New DataView(ds.Tables("lawncutdata"))
Dim dv_one As New DataView(ds.Tables("lawncutdata"))
```

Note that a data view is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

```
Dim dv_all As DataView = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").DefaultView
Dim dv_one As DataView = ds.Tables("lawncutdata").DefaultView
```

In the above code, both `dv_all` and `dv_one` will point to the same instance.